# dgrid / dstore / Rest - How to add additional query parameters to request

Tags: dojo, dgrid, jsonreststore

I used an older version of dgrid (onDemandGrid) toghether with a dojo JsonRestStore.

My web page has some input fields (e.g. date, name etc). After changing one of these fields I change the query of the grid:

***grid.setQuery({y: year, m: month, l: name1, d: flag, e: name2});***

and the Json request was somthing like ***?y=2015&m=5&l=test1&....***

I learned, that with the actual version of dgrid this isn't longer possible.

Is something simelar possible with dgrid/dstore.?
Filtering seems not to be an option, as far as I understood this is only on client side and I'm not able to load all my data. What I need are some dynamic parameters to filter the data on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dstore's equivalent to `dojo/store/JsonRest` is `dstore/Rest` (however, if you don't have a compliant REST API on the server you may want to use `dstore/Request`).

dstore's `filter` method allows you to make arbitrary queries. It returns a collection with any applied filters stored so that they can be included whenever `fetch` or `fetchRange` is called.

```
var store = new Request({ target: '/path/to/service' });
var filteredCollection = store.filter({ y: 2015, m: 5 });
filteredCollection.fetch();
```

would result in the following HTTP request:

```
/path/to/service?y=2015&m=5
```

To use this functionality with dgrid 0.4, you would assign the filtered collection to the grid instance (and dgrid will handle calling `fetch/fetchRange` as necessary):

```
grid.set('collection', store.filter({y: year, m: month}));
```

dgrid 0.4 and dstore introduce a significant shift in the way the grid interacts with the store. In dgrid 0.3 the grid had a much more active role in managing the query state of the store - with dgrid 0.4, this is no longer the case (hence the removal of the `setQuery` method). In dgrid 0.4, it is up to code external to the grid to implement logic related to filtering store data. Whereas in dgrid 0.3 you typically set the grid's `store` property a single time and call `setQuery` whenever you need to filter the data, with dgrid 0.4 you set the `collection` property any time you need to update the filtering. dstore's [`Request`](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/master/docs/Stores.md#request) store allows you to configure the parameter names for `range` and `sort` filtering.